# problem renaming web service in asp.net

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to rename the webservice i made in asp.net website.
I made the changes as below but still it gives error as
"cannot create FileUploading.FileService"
even in .cs file also i changed the class name but it still gives error.

```
  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyService.asmx.cs"
      Class="FileUploading.MyService" %>
```

to

```
  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="FileService.asmx.cs" 
      Class="FileUploading.FileService" %>
```

I'm not having any idea where the problem is. Can you help me?

Comment: can you provide file name of your .cs file and class declaration in it?

Comment: Use VS refactoring option. You will have to (rightlick and) rename the file, as well as select the class name (right click) and rename the class. Should work!

Comment: @KMån Not quite sure, but I think that if he's using the express version that option isn't present

Comment: Check for NameSpace ....

Comment: did you update service reference in client side?

Comment: my webservice old file name was 'MyServ" and i changed its name from MyServ.asmx to FileService.asmx, MyServ.asmx.cs to FileService.asmx.cs and also in both files as shown above and .cs file also changed to public class FileService: System.Web.Services.WebService

Comment: how to update service reference? because in my solution list there is no folder named references but having bin folder with dlls

Comment: Error: Could not create type 'FileUploading.FileService'

Comment: just do what @BreakHead recommended.

Comment: namespace is ther in my .cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't create type must mean the absence of the `namespace` **FileUploading**

Wrap everything inside FileUploading like this.

```
namespace FileUploading
{    
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for FileService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class FileService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {    
        //ctor
        // your methods go here    
    }    
}
```

or if you would like to omit the namespace altogether, change your asmx like

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="FileService.asmx.cs" Class="FileService" %>
```

Comment: namespace FileUploading { /// <summary> /// Summary description for FileService /// </summary> [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] [ToolboxItem(false)] // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] public class FileService: System.Web.Services.WebService { [WebMethod]} this is the change i had done.but still having that error.

Comment: is that a website or web application?

Comment: if i still run website it shows error:There is no source code available for the current location.

Comment: is the asmx.cs inside App_Code folder. if not, put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not but the system isn't lying to you :)

If it says it cannot create the type it means that the type is not defined anywhere.  How are you hosting the project?

Sometimes you may need to stop the local development web server for some changes to be recognized (since everything may still be loaded).

Double-check to make sure your fully qualified class name is 100% correct.

Comment: i m hosting on localhost. and i have changed it in .asmx and .asmx.cs file. are there any other changes remaining that i m skipping?

Comment: Have you stopped the development server and then re-run your application?